# Search mysql database by phrase or seperate key words

Tags: php, mysql, database

Ok so when a user types their search phrase in the search input, I would like it to match the exact phrase or the key words entered.
I.e
So the title of a post is "Search the Database"

```
$searchVal = "Search database";
WHERE post_title LIKE '%" . $searchVal . "%'
```

The above code doesn't find a match as the title has "the" between Search Database.

How could I get it to match.
I thought maybe using explode but Im getting an error:

```
$sVals = explode(" ", $searchVal);
foreach ($sVals as $s) {
    $querySearchVals .= "OR post_title LIKE '%" . $s . "%'";
}
```

Hope that makes sense.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help

```
$search_key = $_POST['searchkey'];  //take the search text from the post method
$search_words = array();
$search_words = explode(" ",$search_key);
$q_string = "";
$last_index = intval(count($search_Words)) - 1;
for($i = 0; $i<count($search_Words);$i++)
{
$q_string = $q_string . " post_title LIKE '%$search_words[$i]%' ";
if($i != $last_index)
  $q_string = $q_string . " OR ";
}
```

And to make it even more accurate, you may skip the articles like A, The, An etc

Comment: That is a better way to approach the problem, but the query is also pulling the post revisions as results. So it displays the post title many times

Comment: To stop it pulling revisions see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897729/wordpress-query-for-posts-is-pulling-up-revisions-as-results/44898319#44898319

Answer (score 0):

You may want to insert the % in between the words and execute with 1 where clause. some thing like below should work.

```
$searchVal = "Search database";
$querySearchVals = "post_title LIKE '%";
$sVals = explode(" ", $searchVal);
foreach ($sVals as $s) {
    $querySearchVals .= $s."%";
}
$querySearchVals .= "'";
echo $querySearchVals;
```

Hope it helps!